# Extract some fields from a part json part text log in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am fairly new to splunk and still learning.
I have a splunk event which is a mix of some texts and json in between. (This isn't the complete log)

```
2021-02-14 00:00:03,596 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets -> 1692
2021-02-14 00:00:03,596 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.CommonUtils - {"Header":{"AppId":"DFG686","Type":"Inbound","RecId":"416c627c-41a7-428e-a871-5317c4842fe5","StartTS":"2021-02-14T05:00Z","Ver":"2.0.0"},"Application":{"APP_OS":"Linux 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64","APP_Runtime":"Java 1.8.0_282","APP_AppName":"DQ-bapm","APP_AppVersion":"1.0.0","Host":"zebra.cdc.growl.com/10.102.180.53","Channel":"Other"},"Service":{"Key":"DQ2bapm","URL":"https://growl-test.DQ.com/rest/2.0/assets?limit=1000&offset=1000&typeId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031302&communityId=595b27d3-ff42-45e4-8dc7-0172f7d82693&domainId=2c8b39ea-0d7f-445f-acc2-a1fb3a9a12db&statusId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005009","CallType":"REST","Operation":"GET"},"Results":{"Elapsed":"0","TraceLevel":"DEBUG"},"Security":{"Vendor":"growl"}}
2021-02-14 00:00:03,795 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets -> 1692
2021-02-14 00:00:03,795 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets in appAssetList-> 1692
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - List of Applications in DQ to be marked "Obsolete in bapm": 
[487684fgfg, hfkeh708089, fgdh678, SDF75664, dffg0007643]
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## Total Application count from bapm ##1696
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## Total Application Asset in DQ ##1692
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## No of Application to Obsolete in DQ ##5
```

How can I extract the below :

```
List of Applications in DQ to be marked "Obsolete in bapm": 
[487684fgfg, hfkeh708089, fgdh678, SDF75664, dffg0007643]
Total Application count from bapm ##1696
Total Application Asset in DQ ##1692
No of Application to Obsolete in DQ ##5
```

I tried something like below which was suggested for one similar case in another post but this didn't work:

```
index=hdt sourcetype=dq2 |  rex field=_raw "(?msi)(?<Total Application count from BAPM>\{.+\}$)"
| spath input="Total Application count from BAPM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression, perhaps wrongly, that you believe the `rex` command will search all events concurrently.  That is not the next.  Splunk processes each event individually and independently.  The query must be prepared to find any of the target strings in any event.

````
| makeresults 
| eval data="2021-02-14 00:00:03,596 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets -> 1692~
2021-02-14 00:00:03,596 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.CommonUtils - {\"Header\":{\"AppId\":\"AD00006933\",\"Type\":\"Inbound\",\"RecId\":\"416c627c-41a7-428e-a871-5317c4842fe5\",\"StartTS\":\"2021-02-14T05:00Z\",\"Ver\":\"2.0.0\"},\"Application\":{\"APP_OS\":\"Linux 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64\",\"APP_Runtime\":\"Java 1.8.0_282\",\"APP_AppName\":\"DQ-bapm-Integration\",\"APP_AppVersion\":\"1.0.0\",\"Host\":\"zebra.cdc.growl.com/10.102.180.53\",\"Channel\":\"Other\"},\"Service\":{\"Key\":\"DQ2bapm\",\"URL\":\"https://growl-test.DQ.com/rest/2.0/assets?limit=1000&offset=1000&typeId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031302&communityId=595b27d3-ff42-45e4-8dc7-0172f7d82693&domainId=2c8b39ea-0d7f-445f-acc2-a1fb3a9a12db&statusId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005009\",\"CallType\":\"REST\",\"Operation\":\"GET\"},\"Results\":{\"Elapsed\":\"0\",\"Message\":\"Invoking DQ REST API\",\"TraceLevel\":\"DEBUG\"},\"Security\":{\"Vendor\":\"growl\"}}~
2021-02-14 00:00:03,795 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets -> 1692~
2021-02-14 00:00:03,795 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.RetrieveDataFromDQ - Total Application assets in appAssetList-> 1692~
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - List of Applications in DQ to be marked \"Obsolete in bapm\": 
[AD00007661, AD00007470, AD00007539, AD00007549, AD00007643]~
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## Total Application count from bapm ##1696~
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## Total Application Asset in DQ ##1692~
2021-02-14 00:00:04,499 [[bapm2DQ].bapmprojectFlow.stage1.02] INFO  com.growl.hdt.dmt.DQ.bapm.ComparebapmDQRecords - ## No of Application to Obsolete in DQ ##5"
| eval data=split(data,"~")
| mvexpand data
| eval _raw=data
| fields - data
```Above just sets up test data```
```Use rex to extract fields```
| rex "List of Applications in DQ to be marked \\\"Obsolete in bapm\\\":\s*(?<Obsolete_in_bapm>.*)"
| rex "Total Application count from bapm ##(?<ApplicationCount>\d+)"
| rex "Total Application Asset in DQ ##(?<Asset_in_DQ>\d+)"
| rex "No of Application to Obsolete in DQ ##(?<Obsolete_in_DQ>\d+)"
```The stats commands groups the extracted fields into a single event```
| stats values(*) as *
````

Comment: Thanks @RichG I have below questions:
1. Do we have to pass the value to the data field? How will that make it a generalized query?
2. If the target string is in multiple events, how will this query handle it?
3. Can I use my index and sourcetype in the beginning of the query?

Comment: See the comments in the query.  1. Do NOT pass the value to the data field.  Remove everything before the "Use rex to extract fields" line. 2. The `stats` command groups events. 3. Yes, absolutely.  Replace everything before the "Use rex to extract fields" line with your index and sourcetype.

Comment: Thanks @RichG ..With the test data set up ( your query) I was getting the data corresponding to all the 4 target searches.
But when I just run the part below rex to extract fields I am only getting Asset_in_DQ and Obsolete_in_DQ ( only 2 target searches) and various others fields like sourcetype eventtype connector etc. which I don't need.

Comment: I tried the below:
index=hdt sourcetype=hdt_DQ_bapm_logs 
| rex "List of Applications in DQ to be marked \\\"Obsolete in bapm\\\":\s*(?<Obsolete_in_bapm>.*)"
| rex "Total Application count from bapm ##(?<ApplicationCount>\d+)"
| rex "Total Application Asset in DQ ##(?<Asset_in_DQ>\d+)"
| rex "No of Application to Obsolete in DQ ##(?<Obsolete_in_DQ>\d+)"
```The stats commands groups the extracted fields into a single event```
| stats values(*) as *

Comment: Can you please advise where I am getting this wrong?

Comment: Use the `fields` or `table` command to show only the fields you want to see.
Run the search in Verbose mode and look in the Events tab to verify the expected events are part of the search and that they match the regular expressions.  Adjust the regexes as necessary.

Comment: You are awesome !! Thanks for all your help !! :)